# How do I create a test app to create many screenshots in UE4?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'd like to create a test application for my Unreal Engine based game to create screenshots. I'd like to place many (possibly thousands) of cameras throughout the maps and then have my test application enumerate them all and take a screen capture at each camera location.

I came across [Taking Screenshots](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Basics/Screenshots), but wanted to first check to see if this isn't already built into UE4 in the editor, or some tool. I'm also aware of the [Screenshot Comparison Tool](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/Automation/ScreenShotComparison), but that doesn't seem to be what I need because I don't really want to use UE4 to do the image matching, but instead just want a directory full of images that I can do with what I want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly what you want to do but I found this article very interesting: https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/blog/capturing-stereoscopic-360-screenshots-videos-movies-unreal-engine-4?sessionInvalidated=true

It explains how people at Ninja Theory Ltd proceeded to produce their 360 video trailer which is, in the end, producing two 360 screenshots per frame.

So what they did was having everything exported in a folder (as a sequence of images) and then did what they wanted with it. (In this case put them all together with ffmpeg to make a video)

They used a plugin, I do not know if it can be tweaked not to make 360 captures but the built-in "take screenshot" from UE4 could work for you.

More specifically to what you need, you could probably store all positions/transform in an array, loop over it when you want to make the screenshot. Each step, you place your Camera at the specific position, make sure it is the current active camera to change the "view" and take a screenshot.
Taking screenshots and setting parameters such as export folder, resolution etc. ... can be called via console commands and console commands can be executed from code or blueprint using the "*execute console command*" node (there is an example in the article).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best bet you have is rendering camera to a texture.
this way you can have multiple inactive camera then iterate through them, activate them, capture their screen view and going to the next one.

for basic tutorial have a look at 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9iho861SlY